# как выдать роль на определённом сервере, зная его ID?

Tags: python, discord.py

Делаю функцию верификации для своего сервера. Нужно, чтобы при написании в личку бота команды .верификация бот выдавал роль на определённом сервере(айди которого указано заранее).

На коленке написал это:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.dm_only()
async def верификация(ctx, code):
    if code == '162933':
        member = ctx.message.author
        await member.add_roles(discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=891743318852116490))
```

Ошибка:
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'add_roles'`

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: исправил, надеюсь так лучше

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
@commands.dm_only()
async def верификация(ctx, code):
    if code == '162933':
        guild = bot.get_guild(425269255538343936)
        guild_members = [roles.id for roles in guild.members]
        if ctx.message.author.id in guild_members:
            member = discord.utils.get(guild.members, id=ctx.message.author.id)
```